# Breakpoint not loading in VS Code with Firefox Dev Edition

Tags: visual-studio-code, firefox-developer-edition

I am able to set and have verified breakpoints. The breakpoints are hit in VS Code when using Firefox but not when using Firefox Developer Edition. Anyone else run into this issue?